# Как скрыть виджет PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, hide, show

Каким образом скрыть виджет в *PyQt5*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060703/how-to-change-the-visibility-of-overlapped-widgets-in-pyqt-based-on-signals

Comment: @Victor VosMottor thanks Monica Виктор на страже ))) Молодчина. Можем поговорить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yourwidget.hide()
```

```
yourwidget.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

> **QWidget.show()**
>
> Показывает виджет и его дочерние виджеты.
>
> Это эквивалентно вызову  `showFullScreen()`, `showMaximized()` или  `setVisible(True)`, в зависимости от поведения платформы по умолчанию для флагов окна.

---

> **QWidget.hide()**
>
> Скрывает виджет. Эта функция эквивалентна `setVisible(False)`.
>
> Примечание. Если вы работаете с `QDialog` или его подклассами и вызываете функцию `show()` после этой функции, диалоговое окно будет отображаться в исходном положении.